# Extract Data Between Delimeter In NVarchar Field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a `nvarchar(1000)` data type field that holds data like this
`name_Test_1
 name_Test1_2
 name_Test2_3`

Now the data I want to extract is what is between the `_` so the data I would want extracted would be

```
Test
Test1
Test2
```

I tried the below syntax, but since the string has two `_` in it then the data I have returned is 1, 2, 3 - how should this query be changed so that I get the middle string?

```
Declare @Red Table (fname nvarchar(1000))

Insert Into @Red (fname) Values
('name_Test_1'), ('name_Test1_2'), ('name_Test2_3') 

Select
RIGHT(fname,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(fname))-1) as RightHalf
FROM @Red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
declare @name varchar(20) = 'name_Test_1'

select SUBSTRING(@name,CHARINDEX('_',@name,0)+1, (CHARINDEX('_',@name,CHARINDEX('_',@name,0)+1)) - CHARINDEX('_',@name,0)-1)
```